# Django CSS. I get the HTML page with no CSS

Tags: python, django

I have had this problem for a while now, I have been trying to move my CSS file all over the place and changing the settings, and even messing with the media url stuff, which I don't believe I should be now that I have read other questions.

My CSS file is in the /home/justin/test/static/ directory. My templates are in the /test/templates directory.

My settings are:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/justin/test/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/justin/test/static/',
)
```

My urls are:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'views.home'),

    # Static Files
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

)
```

I have all three in my main template.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/style.css" />
```

They come out:

```
<link href="/static/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

The first comes out to the correct file, but it doesn't work.
Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',{})
```

My error from the terminal is:

```
[16/Aug/2013 21:00:21] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 500 1729
```

Comment: In your view's `render_to_response`, are you doing `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` ?

Comment: mentioning what the error is could be helpful !

Comment: How would I incorporate that?

Comment: can you show your view ?

Comment: Just added the view and context_instance.

Comment: @karthikr I tried adding it, alas, didn't work still have the same structured HTML with no CSS.

Comment: `return render_to_response('index.html',{}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: It says there is no generic module, is there something perhaps I didn't import?

Comment: @karthikr That for some reason gave me the same no CSS. Is there something perhaps in the urls.py that I have to do for /static/?

Comment: for django 1.3.1 you can render your template form url `(r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template',
        {'template': 'index.html'}),`  try this

Comment: @kartheek Now I get a 404 error.

Comment: @Justin i have edited my comment removed `/` in regx try that

Comment: It worked, but still no CSS. Why doesn't the Django documentation have a special section or something for this, it seems to be a common problem and extremely hard to track the bug.

Comment: once please remove path (/home/jus....) in   `STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/justin/test/static/',
)` form settings.py

Comment: Nope. I think I am going to head to bed, this little thing has been driving me nuts. Maybe a night's sleep can help me. Thank you for the help and any future help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `request` in `RequestContext` of your views

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Only then your session data will be passed to the template and `{{ STATIC_URL }}` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips to help you solve this problem.

First, anything to do with `MEDIA_` is referring to files that are uploaded to the system by users; and `STATIC_` refers to files that are part of your application.

`STATIC_ROOT` should point to the file system path where the `collectstatic` command will dump all the static files from all your applications. When you are deploying the application into a production environment, you run `collectstatic` (which will overwrite everything in the directory pointed to by `STATIC_ROOT`) and then copy the contents of this directory to a location that is mapped to the *url* that `STATIC_URL` points to.

In summary:

1. If your application needs any static files (images, javascript, css, etc.) create a directory called `static` in your application's directory (the same location where you have `models.py`) and add the files there.
2. `STATIC_ROOT` should point to a directory where all the images, css, javascript, etc. will be dumped by the `collectstatic` command.  This is only used when you want to move your application to a production server. The `collectstatic` command will grab all the files in all the `static` directories in your applications that are listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` (including the ones from the `django.contrib` like the admin interface) and dump them in this directory. You would then take this directory and copy or move it to your web server.
3. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is a directory where any static files that are not part of any specific application should be stored. If this location is set, then django will also look here for static files.
4. `STATIC_URL` = the URL path that is configured in your web server to point to the location where all the files in `STATIC_ROOT` are located.
5. The `{% static %}` tag will always point to the `STATIC_URL` variable. In order to use this tag you **must** have `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of any template that is using the tag; even if the template is inheriting from one that already as the load line in it.
6. You don't need anything fancy in your `urls.py` unless you are using django to serve your static files (which you **should not do**). Use the web server to handle static files. If you are running with `DEBUG = True` and using `runserver`, then django will take care of handling static files for you automatically as a courtesy during development.
7. For any **user uploaded files** which are controlled by the various `MEDIA_*` settings you need to handle these manually during development; and for this you can use the following snippet in your `urs.py`. Again, keep in mind this is *only for development* - do not use this in production:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
           # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
     )
     if settings.DEBUG:
          urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                                document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```

Please read the [static files section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/) in the manual; from where I have summarized the above points.

Finally, you should use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render) when using methods in your views. This makes sure that the proper request context is always sent.

Answer (score 0):

you must use this tag ({% load static from staticfiles %}) in your template :

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />
```

Comment: I am on Django 1.3.1, already tried that from another question.

Answer (score 0):

In your urls, you should serve from the `STATIC_ROOT` not the `MEDIA_ROOT` setting

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT})
```

Also, you need to pass RequestContext on your views, like stated in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In development mode (which means `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py`), to serve static files

Simply put the following lines in `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
# ... the rest of your URLconf here ...
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

In production mode, you should use nginx/apache in front of django to serve static files.

Refs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

There's a line in your question:

```
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Normally, `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` is for user uploaded files, which is a different folder from `settings.STATIC_ROOT`.